# Grouping together text descriptions in Python

Tags: python, text, nlp, cluster-analysis, similarity

I have the following dataset:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Members':['Biology PhD student', 'Chemistry Master student', 'Engineering undergraduate student', 'Administration staff',                           
 'Reception staff', 'Research Associate Chemistry', 'Associate Statistics'], 'UCode':[1,1,1,2,2,1,1],'id':['aaa100','aaa121','aa123','bb212','bb214','aa111','aa109']})

data

             Members                     UCode  id
    0   Biology PhD student                1    aaa100
    1   Chemistry Master student           1    aaa121
    2   Engineering undergraduate student  1    aa123
    3   Administration staff               2    bb212
    4   Reception staff                    2    bb214
    5   Research Associate Chemistry       1    aa111
    6   Associate Statistics               1    aa109
```

where the column `df.Members` contains strings describing the function of each listed member.

Which kind of text analysis would you suggest to find groups of similar Members using only the information (text) of the column `df.Members` ?  In this toy example, for instance, the analysis should return two distinct groups. I am thinking about a measure of similarity between two lists of strings/words. 
Any suggestion/help is very much appreciated.
Thank you,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple equal Word Counter, for instance

```
from collections import Counter

WordCounter = Counter()
for text in members:
    words = text.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        WordCounter[word] += 1

print(WordCounter.most_common(3))
```

> **Output**:
>       [('student', 3), ('staff', 2), ('Associate', 2)]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `string` 'Members' into a `word-vector` and, then, perform a **clustering** of those vectors, if you **don't know** apriori the number of groups, or a **classification** task, if you **do know** the number of classes/groups.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest something to you, I'm not an expert but I found a tool that served me in a somewhat similar case.
[Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html) is a tool for python that support text analysis and some of the features help you find the topics in the documents. Check [this](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html) tutorial i think it will be very useful for you. It will give you an idea about how to used.
Now these are very small documents, so I recommend you look for some way to improve the analysis in this type of data like biterms or something, since their length can cause you some problems. 
I hope this helps you.